# Dynamic Dropdown menu through php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I visited a website a few weeks ago and came across a dynamic drop down menu. I came across a functionality that I am now trying to replicate but do not know how. In the dropdown you picked the desired number of cars and then it reiterated input fields according to the number of cars chosen. I believe this was done through javascript and a loop was involved. Is there a term for this action or way to display things? Also an example of how to accomplish something similar would help?

[image]

Comment: I think it is better to do in with javascript on client side. There is no need here to pull anything from the server. Only create/replicate the needed elements

Comment: @Ivil Alright, I will follow the advice. The question is how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done using java script ,
and here a hint

create a div and put inputs that you want inside it

```
<div id='controls'>
<input type="text" name="car_name" />
</div>
```

and using jQuery change event you can iterate view of controls div

i.e if you have a div with id container , where you will place new controls

```
$('select').change(function(){
 var number = parseInt ($(this).val ());
 //And do for loop here
 for (var i=1;i<=number;i++){
     $('#controls').clone().appendTo($('#container');
  }
});
```

Please enhance this code to fit your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely that this would be done with PHP, since that would require a page refresh.
It's more likely that it would be done with Javascript listening for the onChange event of the Select element (the drop down menu). When the event is detected, Javascript could show / hide div elements (one for each Car), or dynamically create / destroy them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it without refresh, you need use javascript, i have made one example here using jquery:
**HTML CODE**

```
<label>How many cars?</label>
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div id="fields"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var option = $(this).val();
    showFields(option);
    return false;
});
function showFields(option){
    var content = '';
    for (var i = 1; i <= option; i++){
        content += '<div id="field_'+i+'"><label>Car '+i+'</label><br /><label>Model:</label> <input id="model_'+i+'" /><br /><label>Maker:</label> <input id="maker_'+i+'" /><br /><label>Year:</label> <input id="year_'+i+'" /><br /><div><br />';
    }
    $('#fields').html(content);
}
```

Here the example: http://jsfiddle.net/zbzjm/1/